# Adding a column to a Polars LazyFrame with data generated form another column

Tags: python, python-polars, lazyframe

I am using the polars dataframe package to scan a large dataset. I then try to add a column which is a Fast Fourier Transform (np.fft.ftt) of another column. The new column is created, however every row is a list of all the data created from every row of the other column.

I am new to polars so seeking some expert advice as to how to modify this code. I have generated a simple code that illustrates the problem below along with an image of the output:

```
import polars as pl
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

# Create a sample Parquet data frame
data = {'acol': [1, 2, 3, 4, 5],
        'bcol': [10, 20, 30, 40, 50]}
df = pl.DataFrame(data)

# Save the data frame to a Parquet file
df.write_parquet('sample_data.parquet')

pdata = pl.scan_parquet('sample_data.parquet')

# Define a custom function to compute FFT
def compute_fft(row):
    row = np.nan_to_num(row)  # Replace NaN values with zeros
    return np.fft.fft(row).real.astype(np.float32)

features, feature_cols = [pl.col('acol')], ['acol']

#Take FFT of 'bcol' and create a new column 'bcol_fft'
bcol_fft = pl.col('bcol').cast(pl.Float32).map_batches(compute_fft).alias('bcol_fft')

# Add the new column to the features list
features.append(bcol_fft)

# Add the corresponding feature column name
feature_cols.append('bcol_fft')

pdata = pdata.with_columns(
    features
).select(feature_cols)
```

`pdata.columns`

['acol', 'bcol_fft']

`pdata.fetch(5)`

[printing the first few lines of pdata](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6czi7.jpg)

The data under 'bcol_fft' is the same for every row and composed of all the FFT taken from 'bcol'.

How can I modify this code so there is a single data point for every row?

I have tried various variations of line that takes the FFT. This version is the only one that produces data, all others have produces various errors.

Thank you for your help

Answer (score 1):

Your function is returning a single numpy array which is being "broadcasted" to the full length of the dataframe.

We can see a similar example here using a list:

```py
def compute_fft(row):
    return [100, 200, 300, 400, 500]
    
df.with_columns(bcol_fft = compute_fft(pl.col('bcol')))
```

```
shape: (5, 3)
┌──────┬──────┬───────────────────┐
│ acol ┆ bcol ┆ bcol_fft          │
│ ---  ┆ ---  ┆ ---               │
│ i64  ┆ i64  ┆ list[i64]         │
╞══════╪══════╪═══════════════════╡
│ 1    ┆ 10   ┆ [100, 200, … 500] │
│ 2    ┆ 20   ┆ [100, 200, … 500] │
│ 3    ┆ 30   ┆ [100, 200, … 500] │
│ 4    ┆ 40   ┆ [100, 200, … 500] │
│ 5    ┆ 50   ┆ [100, 200, … 500] │
└──────┴──────┴───────────────────┘
```

If you return a `pl.Series` instead, the result is flattened/unpacked into 1 value per row.

```
def compute_fft(row):
    return pl.Series([100, 200, 300, 400, 500])
    
df.with_columns(bcol_fft = compute_fft(pl.col('bcol')))
```

```
shape: (5, 3)
┌──────┬──────┬──────────┐
│ acol ┆ bcol ┆ bcol_fft │
│ ---  ┆ ---  ┆ ---      │
│ i64  ┆ i64  ┆ i64      │
╞══════╪══════╪══════════╡
│ 1    ┆ 10   ┆ 100      │
│ 2    ┆ 20   ┆ 200      │
│ 3    ┆ 30   ┆ 300      │
│ 4    ┆ 40   ┆ 400      │
│ 5    ┆ 50   ┆ 500      │
└──────┴──────┴──────────┘
```

Comment: To clarify your last sentence a bit. `map_batches` expects that the function it runs will return a Series. `map_elements` doesn't, it expects just values.

Comment: @jqurious - Thank you so much for an excellent response and the education. It is now working and clear for me.

Comment: @Dean MacGregor - Thank you for the clarification.